# Snap Tolerance in Openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3

Maybe a simple question but I cannot work out how can I remove the snap tolerance when drawing a polygon in Openlayers 3?

There is a snapTolerance under draw options but I don't want any snapping - I tried adding a '-1' but that didn't help, and '0' still seems to snap.

Comment: snapTolerance is in pixel value, you can just set it to 1. I don't understand why would you want to disable it in the first place

Comment: Because users always double click to try and finish a shape, this then starts another polygon so I just want to disable snapping all together. Setting as 1 will still mean that snapping is active unfortunately, even though the pixel value is so small.